# why do people say implied volatility is a better predictor of stock price than the actual stock price?

Tags: options

why do people say implied volatility is a better predictor of stock price than the actual stock price changes itself (ie historical data etc), even though implied volatility comes from the options market, that data still comes from the changes in the actual stock price and people make predictions of that and then this drives the demand and supply of the options (to an extent)
am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Past results do not necessarily indicate future performance.

IV reflects the amount of *uncertainty* that there is about a stock's future performance. The higher the IV, the more uncertainty the market expects. It's not necessarily *better*, but historical volatility does not take into account recent news about a stock, and implied volatility is all about *future* performance, not what the stock has done in the past.

If a company's sock price has been stable for recent history, but then announces a discovery/invention/merger/etc. - that might introduce significant uncertainty about the future. What will happen if the new venture succeeds? What will happen if it fails? What are the odds of success? All of that goes into the market's expectation of future performance and is not reflected in the price history.

Also, just to be clear, implied volatility does not predict specific movements. It provides a *range* of probabilities that the market thinks the stock will move a certain amount in ether direction. Meaning the IV may predict (mathematically) that there is a 60% chance that a stock will move 30% in either direction over some time period. It does NOT say what direction the stock will move. In other words, it can give you a *range* of possible stock prices with a certain level of confidence - it cannot tall you exactly how much or even in which direction a stock is expected to move.